# FB Messenger send multiple messages to Webhook

Tags: facebook, rasa

I have developed a Rasa Bot and linked that bot with Facebook Messenger. My bot works perfectly fine. In recent days I am facing an issue in which I receive multiple webhooks against a single message and RASA shows multiple responses against a single message. This happens randomly not on every chat. But happens mostly when a new user tries to send a message through FB. My deployment is getting delayed due to this issue and I am unable to find and issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If your system doesn’t respond to an incoming webhook requests with 200 OK in 20 seconds or less, Facebook will send the same update again (initially, if it continues to happen, there will be an automatic unsubscribe.) If you can’t guarantee that at all times, but there might be situations where you processed the incomming message, but responded to late occasionally - then you might have to record some unique message ID or whatever there is, on your end, so that you can avoid responding a second time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I got your point. Actually I am using Rasa SDK default code to handle the webhooks. If that thing needs to be changed - then I need to update the code Rasa SDK files. Can you help me with that change or just show me path for that (If possible). Again thank you so much.

Comment: No, I don’t know anything about this Rasa thing, I can only advise you on things from the Facebook API side.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. Really appreciated.